# Can't use combination of gradiants for multiple losses functions of a multi-output keras model

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent

I am doing a time-series forecasting in Keras with a CNN and the EHR dataset. The goal is to predict both what molecule to give to the patient and the time until the next patient visit. I have to implement a bi-objective gradient descent based on [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/298910404_A_multiobjective_steepest_descent_method_with_applications_to_optimal_well_control). The algorithm to implements is here (end of page 7, the beginning of page 8):

[image: algorithm at end of page 7]

[image: algorithm at the beginning of page 8]

The model I choose is this one :

[image: model to train]

With time-series of length 3 as input (correspondings to 3 consecutive visits for a client)
And 2 outputs:

- the atc code (the code of the molecule to predict)
- the time to wait until the next visit (in categories of months: 0,1,2,3,4 for >=4)

both outputs use the `SparseCategoricalCorssentropy` loss function.

when I start to implement the first operation: `gs - gl` I have this error :
[image: errir]

Some values in my gradients are at `None` and I don't know why. My optimizer is defined as follow: `optimizer=tf.Keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3` when compiling my model.

Also, when I try some operations on gradients to see how things work, I have another problem: only one input is taken into account which will pose a problem later because I have to consider each loss function separately:

With this code, I have this output message : `WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['outputWaitTime/kernel:0', 'outputWaitTime/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss.`

```py
EPOCHS = 1

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    with tf.GradientTape() as ATCTape, tf.GradientTape() as WTTape:
        predictions = model(xTrain,training=False)
        ATCLoss = loss(yTrain[:,:,0],predictions[ATC_CODE])
        WTLoss = loss(yTrain[:,:,1],predictions[WAIT_TIME])

    ATCGrads = ATCTape.gradient(ATCLoss, model.trainable_variables)
    WTGrads  = WTTape.gradient(WTLoss,model.trainable_variables)
    grads = ATCGrads + WTGrads

    model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

With this code, it's okay, but both losses are combined into one, whereas I need to consider both losses separately

```py
EPOCHS = 1

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(xTrain,training=False)
        ATCLoss = loss(yTrain[:,:,0],predictions[ATC_CODE])
        WTLoss = loss(yTrain[:,:,1],predictions[WAIT_TIME])
        lossValue = ATCLoss + WTLoss

    grads = tape.gradient(lossValue, model.trainable_variables)

    model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

I need help to understand why I have all of those problems.

The notebook containing all the code is here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1b6UorAAEddNKFQCxaK1Wsuj09U645KhU?usp=sharing

The implementation begins in the part `Model Creation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get `None` in `ATCGrads` and `WTGrads` is because two gradients corresponding loss is wrt different outputs `outputATC` and `outputWaitTime`, if
outputs value is not using to calculate the loss then there will be no gradients wrt that outputs hence you get `None` gradients for that output layer. That is also the reason why you get `WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['outputWaitTime/kernel:0', 'outputWaitTime/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss`, because you don't have those gradients wrt each loss. If you combine losses into one then both outputs are using to calculate the loss, thus no `WARNING`.

So if you want do a list element wise subtraction, you could first convert `None` to `0.` before subtraction, and you cannot using `tf.math.subtract(gs, gl)` because it require shapes of all inputs must match, so:

```
import tensorflow as tf

gs = [tf.constant([1., 2.]), tf.constant(3.), None]
gl = [tf.constant([3., 4.]), None, tf.constant(4.)]

to_zero = lambda i : 0. if i is None else i
gs = list(map(to_zero, gs))
gl = list(map(to_zero, gl))
sub = [s_i - l_i for s_i, l_i in zip(gs, gl)]
print(sub)
```

Outpts:

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([-2., -2.], dtype=float32)>, 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>, 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-4.0>]
```

Also beware the `tape.gradient()` will return **a list or nested structure of Tensors (or IndexedSlices, or None), one for each element in sources. Returned structure is the same as the structure of sources**; Add two list `[1, 2] + [3, 4]` in python will not give you `[4, 6]` like you do in numpy array, instead it will combine two list and give you `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: I am wondering: for the transpose and norm operations, shouldn't I make both grads in a 1D vector do what I need to do, and then take them back in the initial shape to use in the `apply_gradients` function?

Comment: @Adrien `grads` you provided to `apply_gradients` is just a list of values of gradients with same structure as `model.trainable_variables`, change it however you want as long as the value is valid and structure is same after you processed it

Comment: Yes, I tested and it kind of worked. Thank you for your help, I have a report to write for this project, you will be mentioned :)

Comment: @Adrien Cool, Glad to help : )